# How to call the function inside the Smarty Foreach Loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I want to call the function inside the foreach loop in smarty template, If anyone well known in smarty templates and it's functions, please help me in this to resolve this issue.

***Example in PHP :***

```
<?php
function array_combine_($keys, $values)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
        $result[$k][] = $values[$i];
    }
    array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = (count($v) == 1)? array_pop($v): $v;'));
    return $result;
}
$country = array("India","United States","United Kingdom","India","Australia");
$city    = array("Coimbatore","Newyork","London","Bangalore","Melborne");
$output  = array_combine_($country, $city);
$get_array_keys = array_keys($output);
$get_array_values = array_values($output);
$get_count = count(array_keys($output));
for($i=0;$i<$get_count;$i++){
    if(is_array($get_array_values[$i])){
        echo "<b>".$get_array_keys[$i]."</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;".implode(",",$get_array_values[$i])."<br>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<b>".$get_array_keys[$i]."</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;".$get_array_values[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**Output :**

```
India - Coimbatore,Bangalore
United States - Newyork
United Kingdom - London
Australia - Melborne
```

***Example in Smarty :***

```
{foreach from=$companies item=record key=key}
{$record.country}
{$record.city}
{/foreach}
```

Now how to pass this {$record.country} and {$record.city} values into array_combine_($arg1,$arg2); inside the {foreach} loop,like the following :

```
{foreach from=$companies item=record key=key}
{$record.country}
{$record.city}
array_combine_({$record.country},{$record.city});
{/foreach}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't advice you to put such functions inside Smarty... Better inside your PHP just prepare the result you want to output and in smarty only display it.

Comment: so the php function not possible to call inside the smarty template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you I don't ADVICE you to do that..

If you are sure what are you doing at your template you can describe your function and use it. Just put php tags so smarty don't parse it..

```
{php}
    function array_combine_(){
    }
{/php}
{foreach from=$companies item=record key=key}
    {$record.country}
    {$record.city}
    array_combine_({$record.country},{$record.city});
{/foreach}
```

Comment: @JohnPeter no problem, but its a lot better do that out from smarty, its not right to be there.

Comment: Sure, i know that way, but i want to know if it is possible or not inside that smarty template, that's it. For that you are given the solution for that, that's y i accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepare the array_combine() result from php side and pass that to smarty to display it. Try to reduce more function on smarty side.

In smarty use only the functions available by its one like uppercase etc. Dont try to use php function inside smarty.

Comment: {$company_obj->array_combine({$record.country},{$record.city})} it's not working for me friend.

Comment: please go through my answer once again.

Comment: so the php function not possible to call inside the smarty template ?

Comment: You call. Please check the below link for that. But its not a good practice. http://swarajketan.com/2010/07/08/how-to-call-php-functions-inside-smarty-template-directly/